# DEM Processing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, raster-calculator, raster-conversion

I have a question regarding DEM. I have downloaded SRTM DEM 30 m and I did a mosaic for the data using Mosaic tools in Arcmap to a Mosaic to a new raster. However, I got a DEM raster with values of 0-255 . I need to have a DEM values with meters not with the values of 0-255. I did convert the raster to 32-float but I still get the same value 0-255. and the cell size is 0.0002777.

Any idea how to convert DEM raster with values of 0-255 to values represent elevations?

Comment: Not really sure why that is. Are the pre-mosaic rasters projected? Converting to 32-float after the mosaic has created 0-255 values probably won't help.  Need to sort out the processing of the mosaic.  Other options are [mosaic datasets](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009t0000003p000000) if you have a standard or advanced license.

Comment: Are you positive that is a DEM, and not the hillshade of a DEM?

Comment: I agree with @Barbarossa, it sounds like you have downloaded an _image_ of the SRTM data and not the data itself. I would go back to the site you downloaded it and check what you downloaded. I've used the USGS EarthExplorer website in the past to get SRTM data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the mosaic, make sure you select the same pixel type as what your input DEMs are using - for instance "8_BIT_SIGNED", and not "8_BIT_**UN**SIGNED". "8_BIT_**UN**SIGNED" would give you a 0-255 value. 
ESRI help on the topic is available [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000008n000000).

Comment: DEMs are far more likely to be 16_BIT_SIGNED or 32_BIT_FLOAT, though I suppose an extremely low-lying region could have an 8-bit DEM (e.g., Florida in meters, though not feet).

Comment: Sure, though the 0-255 values are only available for 8_bit_unsigned in the create mosaic tool, so I reckoned this is what what used here.